# Entity Framework model editor association lines incorrectly displayed

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, model, entity, edmx

I often end up with the associations lines in my .edmx model editor being "messed up".

Normaly, my relations end are directly on the entities, but sometimes when I re-open my .edmx file, most of them are a couple of pixels off (like 25).

It's not really a problem, but I'm wondering if anyone has a trick to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: have you done a merge or changed the XML of the EDMX by hand?

Comment: No manual merging was done to my knowledge at least.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is moving with single entity and everything will fix by itself.

Comment: This is actualyl my workaround for now, I select all entities and move hen one bit to the right with my keyboard arrows. Works well but seams weird.